# How does one filter json after type?

Tags: javascript, json, filter

So, I have a json which looks a little bit like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "edge_followed_by": {
        "count": 22,
        "page_info": {
          "has_next_page": true,
          "end_cursor": "Base64"
        },
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "id",
              "username": "Username",
              "full_name": "played",
              "profile_pic_url": "URL"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to filter out the username. How do I do that?

Comment: What do you mean with `filter`? Do you want to retrieve all usernames or remove them from the object?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `filter` here

Comment: I want to retrieve them, I am sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: `let usernames = json.data.user.edge_followed_by.edges.map(e => e.node.username);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could retrieve it with a map function there

```js
const dataSample = {
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "edge_followed_by": {
        "count": 22,
        "page_info": {
          "has_next_page": true,
          "end_cursor": "Base64"
        },
        "edges": [
          {
            "node": {
              "id": "id",
              "username": "Username",
              "full_name": "played",
              "profile_pic_url": "URL"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}


const getUsernames = data => {
  return data.data.user.edge_followed_by.edges.map(e => e.node.username)
}


console.log(getUsernames(dataSample))
```

:)

Comment: I think this works, although I have yet to find a way to run this

Answer (score 0):

This can be a little tricky to understand from the question first of all.

My interpretation of this is you want to extract a username

"Filtering" also could mean you want to remove something from a collection that passes a condition (or test) of some kind.

For example: Removing all even numbers from an array

```
let x = [1, 2, 4, 5, 6];
let filtered = x.filter(value => value % 2 === 0);
```

Now, I've looked at your json, and I think the best point of targeting this is by getting the "edges" property and running it through an inbuilt function like map; that could be used to get usernames. The `edges` is an array as well.

`data.user.edge_followed_by.edges.map(userObject => userObject.username)`

That would effectively remove all usernames from the `edges` if your tech stack of choice was javascript.

I got this info from a post like: https://coderin90.com/blog/2019/map-js